# Market leading forum software?

Tags: forums

Which systems are considered to be the market leaders in user numbers, reputation and features in the forum software (as opposed to hosted service) field?

Comment: I realise this is slightly subjective, but I am looking for a rough top 3 or 4 - rather than an absolute winner. I'm interested in going with the best regarded offering.

Comment: Guess that makes this community wiki. Don't you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com/)
and
[vBulletin](http://www.vbulletin.com/) dominate the market.

phpBB is free and open source where as vBulletin costs a couple hundred bucks and is closed source. (but sometimes has a few more features)

Comment: If you want to compare site traffic: http://siteanalytics.compete.com/phpbb.com+vbulletin.com/

Answer (score 1):

3 market leaders in forum software, scale, big clients, in no particular order:

1. Jive
2. Lithium
3. LiveWorld

Comment: I agree. They, like you said, target companies and enterprises.

Answer (score 0):

BigBoards lists [what the most popular forums use](http://rankings.big-boards.com/?p=all).